# Shiny apps - embedding reactive expression in if-then statement

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having difficult using reactive expression in Shiny Apps. I'm creating a pie chart from slider input. This all works fine, however, the labels overlap. To avoid this I would like the label "" when the input is zero. The difficulty is that I'm unable to embed a reactive expression within an if-then statement.

Here is an MWE...

File "ui.R"...

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Exposure to English calculator"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      h3("Sleeping"),

      sliderInput("sleep", "How long does your child sleep every day?",
                               min=0, max=15, value=0, step = 0.5),

    h3("School"),
    sliderInput("school", "How long does your child spend in school?",
                min = 0, max = 50, value=0, step = 0.5)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )



  )
))
```

File server.R...

```
library(shiny)

values <- c(1,2)

# Define server logic for slider examples
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  total_sleep <- reactive({7*input$sleep})

  pieLabels<-c("sleep", "school", "other")

  if(total_sleep() == 0) {
    pieLabels[1] <- ""
  }

  output$plot <- renderPlot({ 

    pie(c(total_sleep(), input$school, 50),
        labels = pieLabels,
        col = c("deepskyblue", "orange"),
        height = 1500
    )

  })


})
```

The compilation crashes due to the "if" expression even though I've put the brackets after it, to show that it is derived from a reactive expression.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put all your `total_sleep` code and conditional statement inside the `renderPlot` function:

```
library(shiny)

app <- shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Exposure to English calculator"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        h3("Sleeping"),
        sliderInput("sleep", "How long does your child sleep every day?",
                    min=0, max=15, value=0, step = 0.5),
        h3("School"),
        sliderInput("school", "How long does your child spend in school?",
                    min = 0, max = 50, value=0, step = 0.5)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
      )
    )
  )),
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
      total_sleep <- 7*input$sleep
      pieLabels<-c("sleep", "school", "other")
      if(total_sleep == 0) {
        pieLabels[1] <- ""
      }
      pie(c(total_sleep, input$school, 50),
          labels = pieLabels,
          col = c("deepskyblue", "orange")
      )
    })
  }))

runApp(app)
```

Note that I removed the `height` from `pie` because that argument doesn't exist and that gives out a warning.

Comment: Thanks. Beautiful! I knew it would be something simple, but I was fiddling for hours...